# show only one shortcode type insted of content in post

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to show just a certain short code in post and show all them and no content text

i use below code for my work .

```
$pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
preg_match_all( '/'. $pattern .'/s', $post->post_content, $matches );

if( is_array($matches) && array_key_exists(1, $matches) && in_array('foodcat', $matches[2]) )
{
    $value = $matches[0];
    for($i=1;$i<=sizeof($matches[0]);$i++) {
        echo do_shortcode($value[$i]);
    }
} else {
  // Do Nothing
}
```

But it shows just last 2 `shortcodes` that used in the content and doesn't depend on `shortcode` type ( in this case it is `[foodcat]` )

Comment: try `var_dump($matches)` before the `if` statement and let us know the output.

Comment: it's show something like this , http://pastebin.com/MSrCAE1e